# virtualenv - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'?

Tags: python, django, linux

New to linux, I have install django in virtualenv, but i am not able to import django. Is there any variable path i need to set ?

```
(virs) akash@akash-Inspiron-3542:/usr/virs/bin$ django-admin --version
1.11.10
(virs) akash@akash-Inspiron-3542:/usr/virs/bin$ python
Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan 28 2018, 17:52:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `manage.py` if you want to access django library inside python shell.
Here's a little bit example.

Try:

```
django-admin startproject mysite

cd mysite

./manage.py shell
```

or

```
python manage.py shell
```

Here's what it looks like accessing django library inside python shell. In this case, I use IPython. If you don't have IPython installed, `manage.py` automatically using python shell.

```
In [1]: import django                                                                                                                                                   

In [2]: django.__version__                                                                                                                                              
Out[2]: '3.0'

In [3]: django.get_version()                                                                                                                                            
Out[3]: '3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command and write result here.

```
whereis django-admin
```

probably! django-admin command run from out of virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

run the command

```
pip install django
```